# Showing that a bounded continuous function is zero if an integral with it is zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

The below problem is from an exam in real analysis. Thus, only such methods may be used.

> Show that a bounded continuous function $f:[1,\infty)\mapsto x\in\mathbb{R}$ is identically equal to zero if and only if $$\int_1^\infty f(x)x^{-n}dx=0$$ for $n=8,9,10,\dots$.

This is my attempt. Is it correct?

> The criterion if and only if means that there is an equivalence. Thus, both the implication $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftarrow$ need to be shown.
>   Start with $\Rightarrow$. Thus, assume that $f(x)$ is a bounded and continuous function on $[1,\infty)$ that is identically equal to zero. Thus, $f(x):=0$. Now, we shall prove that $$\int_1^\infty f(x)x^{-n}dx=0.$$ Okay. We have $$\int_1^\infty f(x)x^{-n}dx=\int_1^\infty 0\cdot x^{-n}dx=\int_1^\infty0dx=[c]_1^\infty=c-c=0$$ for some constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Here, it was used that $0\in\mathbb{R}$ is the absorbing element in $\mathbb{R}$. Not let's proceed to $\Leftarrow$. Hence, assume that $$\int_1^\infty f(x)x^{-n}dx=0.$$ Now, we shall prove that $f(x)=0$ on $[1,\infty)$ and that it's bounded and continuous. Assume towards a contradiction that $f(x)\neq0$. Namely, $f(x)>0$, for definitiveness. Thus, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that $f(x_0)=L$ and $L-\epsilon<f(x)<L+\epsilon$ in $x\in[x_0+\delta,x_0-\delta]$ for some $x_0\in[1,\infty)$. Consequently
>       \begin{align*}
>   \int_1^\infty f(x)x^{-n}dx=\int_1^{x_0-\delta}f(x)x^{-n}dx+\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}f(x)x^{-n}dx+\int_{x_0+\delta}^\infty f(x)x^{-n}dx>0
>  \end{align*}
>       which contradicts that $$\int_1^\infty f(x)x^{-n}dx=0.$$ Thus, $f(x)=0$ on $[1,\infty)$. The zero function is trivially bounded and continuous.

Comment: I have a question: Do you assume $\int_1^\infty f(x)x^{-n}dx=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ or just one $n$?

Comment: I think there is a flaw in your second argument. Couldn't it be that $\int_1^{x_0-\delta}f(x)x^{-n}dx < 0$, such that it has the same value as the term in the middle, hence the sum would be zero?

Comment: @humanStampedist: For all $n=8,9,10,...$.

Comment: @humanStampedist: Yeah! I think that you're right. I tried to implement a solution to another problem that I saw, but I see now that they had the additional assumption that $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: In that case the argument is correct, but then you do not need the equality to hold for all $n\geq 8$ to deduce that $f=0$, you just need a single value of $n$.

Comment: It's not for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$, but for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$ greater than 7. Thus, it doesn't work to show it for a single value of $n$.

Comment: In my opinion you need something like Stone-Weierstraß to deduce that $\int f(x)\varphi(x)\, dx=0$ for all $\varphi$ continuous. Then you can apply the Fundamental Theorem of the Calculus of Variations. Do you have versions of these Theorems at your disposal?

Comment: @humanStampedist yes this is needed if you do not have the assumption that $f\geq 0$. With that assumption his argument is fine.

Comment: I don't have that theorem at my disposal. That is, it's not a part of the course. If you have another approach, then you're more than welcome to post that as an answer to the question as my approach seems to be limited to the case when the assumption $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$ is given. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $g(x)=x^{-8}f(x)$, so $g$ is bounded, continuous and *integrable* on $[1,\infty)$. Note that $$\int_1^\infty x^{-n}g(x)\,dx=0\quad(n\ge0).$$Now a suitable version of Stone-Weierstrass shows that $$\int_1^\infty g(x)\phi(x)\,dx=0$$for every $\phi\in C_0([1,\infty))$ (and hence for every $\phi\in C_c([1,\infty))$).

Comment: How does this show that $f(x)=0$? I don't get why you write $g(x)=x^{-8}f(x)$. Is that really valid for any $\phi(x)\in C_0([1,\infty))$? Weren't we going to show that it was 0 if and only if $f(x)\equiv0$ for all $x\in[1,\infty)$?

Comment: I defined $g$ that way because $g$ has the property that $|int x^{-n}g(x)=0$ for all $n\ge0$. Yes, it's valid for all $\phi\in C_0([1,\infty))$. One implication is trivial - for the other if, $g=0$ then $f=0$ follows.

Comment: Alright! I get it now. Thanks a ton!

Comment: No. Hold on! Why do we care about $n$ starting at $n=0$ and instead of $n=8$, and how does it follow that $g(x)=0$ by this argument?

Comment: Come to think of it $n\ge8$ is fine. We still need to define $g$ as I did or similarly to get an integrable function. The version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem for $C_0(X)$, $X$ locally compact, shows that the class of linear combinations of $x^{-n}$ is dense in $C_0([1,\infty))$. Since $\int_1^\infty|g|<\infty$ this shows that $\int_1^\infty g\phi=0$ for every $\phi\in C_0([1,\infty))$. Fix $x\ge1$. Since $g$ is continuous it's clear that there exist $\phi_n\in C_c([1,\infty))$ such that $g(x)=\lim_n\int g\phi_n$. So $g(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} 0=0$. Hence $f(x)=x^8g(x)=0$.

Comment: Okay, so $g(x)=\lim_n\int g\phi_n$ is what shows that $g(x)=0$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said.

Comment: Okay. What is it with $n=8$ that shows that $g(x)$ is integrable? Doesn't it just follow from continuity? Why does continuity of $g(x)$ mean that there exists a $\phi_n\in C_c([1,\infty))$ such that $g(x)=\lim_n\int g\phi_n$?

Comment: Isn't it easier to choose $\phi_n$ as $g$ to find that $$\int_1^\infty g(x)\phi(x)=\int_1^\infty g^2(x)du=0\Rightarrow g(x)=0\Rightarrow x^8f(x)=0\Leftrightarrow f(x)=0$$ where $x\neq0$ as $x\in[1,\infty)$?

Comment: If you like that better fine.